# Network address setup in VirtualBox when moving between a work environment with a “192.168.x.x” range and home where I use a “192.168.1.x” range?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux, ip-address

At work we use RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.

At work, the network is set to use `192.168.x.x` addresses. And so our VirtualBox VM images are set to use this range of addresses.

I brought my laptop at home today, set up a brand new VM, and found I couldn’t test my software because my home network is set to use `192.168.1.x` addresses.

The VM I use is one with the network to be set as "Host-Only" as I told to use this setup.

Now, my question is: Is there an easy way to set the VM to use my home network addresses (`192.168.1.x`) at home and work addresses (`192.168.x.x`) at work?

Comment: Do you mean that the network at your work actually uses one large /16 subnet (with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0)?

Comment: But if it's a "Host-only" network, it doesn't really have any relationship to your real LAN anyway (neither work nor home). It _shouldn't_ be using your home LAN IP addresses because it is not _part of_ that LAN (only bridged mode would make it part of a physical LAN).

Comment: The clean way is to make your images use DHCP, to make all upper levels use the IP addr range that is found, and so make the images work in all environments.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with VirtualBox settings, but doesn't "Host-Only" imply no access via the network (except maybe directly from the host)?

Comment: "Host Only" means Isolated.  Are you sure a working VM was set to Isolated?  On a laptop, moving between host IP addresses, NAT is the very best option for you,

Comment: When I've dealt with this in the past it was far simpler to switch my home network over to the 10.x.x.x range.